# How to close application on sub-activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I'm developing an Android application that has many activities. I have a Logout Activity to check logout, user must input username & password to log out. If that are correct, my application will close and  return to Android Homeboard.

But in logout activity, I can't close my application. I used `Finish()`, but it only closes that activity. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: You do know that you cannot stop the user from returning to the home screen on their own, and then uninstalling your annoying application.

Comment: consider startActivityForResult() it is the answer to your problem.

Comment: Please note Android alone decides which programs begin and end. It is out of your control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there's no 'exit application' method, another way is to call moveTaskToBack(true) which "hides" the current application.

Reference: [moveTaskToback()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#moveTaskToBack%28boolean%29)

Comment: Thanks @Frank. I have used it, and it's helpful. Thanks again :D

Comment: Helpful perhaps but this can create unexpected behavior.  Let the user decide when to close your application.  Hide and seek is not the way.

Comment: The app can still offer a logout button to the user and close connections etc. when clicked.  moveTaskToback() merely complements it by giving the user a visual indicator that they have successfully 'logged out', there's no 'hide and seek' required.

Answer (score 0):

You can return to the homescreen by adding the code

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

combining that with the flag android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" in your android manifest file (when you declare your "Main" activity, should do the trick I think. More documentation on this is available here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Basically, to my knowledge if you set this flag to "true" in the activity accesible through the home screen, the effect will be that every time the user starts the app it should open that activity (regardless of the application's state when the user left it).

Let me know if I can be more useful.

Comment: I dont know clearly how to do it. Can it finish my application?

Answer (score 0):

There are limits but when you start an Activity you have an interesting option called startActivityForResult()   With this you pass a request code and can know when that activity has ended and what the result was.  Problem solved!

Comment: but any activity in my application can call log out activity, and the activity call log out, can called by other activity. If you start log out by startActivityForResult(), that only finish activity call log out. :D and application can not close :D. problem doesnt solved. :)

Comment: Oh closing the application? Let the droid decide! Its not what you want its what the user wants that counts.

Comment: but if user want to close application, they will go to logout screen and input username and pass to close application. If they dont want, they will not go to logout screen